# Vue i18n - adding locale to the URL using routerview

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using a scafolded AspNetCore 2.1 site with VueJS using TypeScript.
I'm trying to integrate the [kazupon i18n](http://kazupon.github.io/) plugin with the router-view. Without the URL integration, it works just fine.

I am not able to get the proper redirects working like `http://localhost/en/product` and `http://localhost/fr/product`

This is the initial `boot.ts`, that uses `VueI18n`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueI18n);

import { messages, defaultLocale } from './lang/i18n';

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: defaultLocale,
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages
})

const routes = [
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
        { path: '/product', component: require('./components/product/product.vue.html') },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: router,
    i18n: i18n,
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html'))
});
```

So far I have tried prefixing `routes` but it just breaks the functionality:

```
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: `/${defaultLocale}`,
},
{
    path: '/:locale',
    children: [
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
        { path: '/counter', component: require('./components/product/product.vue.html') },
    ]
}];
```

I've also tried relying on `router.beforeEach` to set the locale.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let language = to.params.locale;
    if (!language) {
        language = 'en';
    }

    i18n.locale = language;
    next();
});
```

This does not function either.

I've drawn inspiration from [github.com/ashour/vuejs-i18n-demo](https://github.com/ashour/vuejs-i18n-demo) and [vue-i18n-sap-multilingual-best-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41953836/vue-i18n-sap-multilingual-best-practice), but it seems that during the i18n migration, some samples may have been obsolete or lost and those use-cases no longer function.

Comment: Please note that in the example with path: `'/:locale'` you are missing the  
            `component: {
                template: '<router-view />',
            },`
element. I mean like [here](https://github.com/ashour/vuejs-i18n-demo/blob/127936b98a631c1a538b3c6a70ebe591d41d3133/src/router/index.js#L21).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

what you primarily needed is to specify the [`base`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) option in the vue-router constructor.

But first, you need to extract the locale from the url:

```
let locale = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]+).*/i,'$1');
```

and then specify the `base` in your `VueRouter` constructor:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    ...
    base: (locale.trim().length && locale != "/") ? '/' + locale : undefined
    ...
});
```

and last but not the least, pass the locale into your `VueI18n` constructor:

```
const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: (locale.trim().length && locale != "/") ? locale : defaultLocale,
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages
})
```

See the updated example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueI18n);

import { messages, defaultLocale } from './lang/i18n';

var locale = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]+).*/i,'$1');


const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: (locale.trim().length && locale != "/") ? locale : defaultLocale ,
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages
})

const routes = [
        { path: '/', component: require('./components/home/home.vue.html') },
        { path: '/product', component: require('./components/product/product.vue.html') },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    base: (locale.trim().length && locale != "/") ? '/' + locale : undefined,
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: router,
    i18n: i18n,
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html'))
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Julian! We're making progress. I got the redirects working on all the subpages with the `base: '/' + locale` trick.. It's still not working on the home page though; on the '/'. It appears without /en, although the translations do work just fine. Any idea on how I can do the redirects for the home?

Comment: I don't really understand what you meant. Do you mean like `http://localhost/` instead of `http://localhost/en`?

Comment: Ah, and I've seen that the defaultLocale is not used anywhere in the sample, so I'm just instantiating the locale to defaultLocale if it is empty: `if (locale == "" || locale == "/") locale = defaultLocale;`

Comment: Yes, that will fix it.

Comment: Yes, I get `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost/en`, but for the other pages it works just fine. I get  `http://localhost/en/product`

Comment: update the base, `base: (locale.trim().length && locale != "/") ? '/' + locale : undefined,`

Comment: Also you should NOT assign defaultLocale to locale as it will affect the condition I've mentioned above for the `base` option. you should just do `locale : locale.trim().length && locale != "/" ? locale : defaultLocale`

Comment: haha! super cool, thanks for the tip, I figured out that the assignment of `defaultLocale` to `locale` was better placed in the `base`. Now the solution is 99% there. It works perfectly now on the homepage while navigating the app through the menu. Is it possible to do the auto redirect when navigating with the browser for the first time? For example, when I type in the browser `http://localhost`, it still doesn't add the `/en`, but as soon as I start to go throug the menu, it does.

Comment: I think, you don't need to do redirection and force it to redirect to en. Is there a reason why you want to force it to redirect to the default locale?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176711/discussion-between-ovi-and-julian-paolo-dayag).

Comment: HI @Ovi, please don't forget to mark this as the answer :) Nice talking to you!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you very much @Julian Paolo Dayag, there were three problems with the approach in my question:

1. it requires a redirect to `"/" + defaultLocale + to.path`
2. the children routes shouldn't start with `/`, they should be `product` instead of `/product`
3. The `router.beforeEach...` is no longer needed

I ended up with this code:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: `/${defaultLocale}`
  },
  {
    path: `/(fr|en)`,
    component: require("./components/app/routertemplate.vue.html"),
    children: [
      { path: "", component: require("./components/home/home.vue.html") },
      {
        path: "product",
        component: require("./components/product/product.vue.html")
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/(.*)",
    redirect: (to: any) => {
      return "/" + defaultLocale + to.path;
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: What do you have inside `routertemplate.vue.html` ?

Comment: @tomfl I guess just a simple `<router-view />` to render the nested paths, see [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view).