# Vuejs dynamic Vi18n base url

Tags: vue.js, locale, vue-router, service-worker, vue-i18n

How can you set a dynamic base url using the vi18n as a base so the link would look like `<host>/<vi18n>/`, so when the user changes the locale it will be displayed on the url, however if i refresh the page with the url like `<host>/<vi18n>/` it results to a page not found but it works when refreshing a `<host>/`. I also used a service-worker for it to work offline.

Comment: see this question please:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065687/vue-i18n-adding-locale-to-the-url-using-routerview

Comment: @MahmoodAbbas i tried to follow their conversation about the dynamic base and applied it to my code. thank you for the reply, however when using it in offline mode service-worker it still shows the page not found when refreshing with `/en/` it only works with `/`